# How Can i update the live date time in c# blazor web page

Tags: c#, datetime, blazor-server-side, live-update

I am trying to set the live DateTime in blazor webpages. I tried using Datetime.now . it's not updating the live time. I want to do it without using javascript.

Any help regarding this issue?

Comment: No.  The time comes from the machine the server is running.  So you need to change the machine time and you probably do not have the permissions running from a remote client.

Comment: I think Sandeep just wants to display the Date/Time.

Comment: once the time is set on page load. it is not updating live. I need to refresh the page time to check the time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need a Timer. Shortest sample I could think of:

```
@page "/"
@using System.Threading    
@implements IDisposable

<p>@theTime</p>

@code{

    string theTime;    
    Timer aTimer;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        aTimer = new Timer(Tick, null, 0, 1000);        
    }

    private void Tick(object _)
    {
        theTime = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        aTimer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Henk, do you know  if the Timer runs on the server or on the client?

Comment: Wherever the Blazor code runs. If you want local (Client side) time in a Blazor Server app you might need some extra logic.

Comment: @HenkHolterman i would love to know your approach to solve that in blazor wasm

Comment: On Blazor Wasm you should not need any solution - it should be local time already. The server could be offline and your clock still ticking.

Answer (score 1):

Similar one, using "System.Timers"

```
@page "/digitalclock"
@using System.Timers
@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>Digital Clock</PageTitle>

<h1>@currentTime</h1>

@code {
   private string currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
   
   private Timer? secondsTimer;

   protected override void OnInitialized()
   {
      //one second interval
      secondsTimer = new Timer(1000);
      secondsTimer.Enabled = true;
      secondsTimer.AutoReset = true;
      secondsTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => UpdateTime();
   }

  private void UpdateTime()
  {
     currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
     InvokeAsync(() =>
     {
         StateHasChanged();
     });
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
      secondsTimer?.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: I used System.Timers and it didn't tick. The reason being I used StateHasChanged() instead of wrapping it into InvokeAsync() which meant that it ran on a new thread. Thanks :)